# How to show 'pagingtoolbar' when the window size changed in Extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

This question is about the pagingtoolbar layout.
My target is to show it at the bottom of window whenever the window size changed.
But now when reduce window size the toolbar is hidden.
pageingtoolbar codes:

```
{
    xtype:'pagingtoolbar',
    store:'Users',
    dock:'bottom',
    displayInfo:true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 'pagingtoolbar' is no layout and not window, it is a component. Here is a version that I used in a early 4.x project. You may need to tweak it at some point cause it was build for a customer requirement.

```
/**
* @class Ext.ux..toolbar.Paging
* @extends Ext.toolbar.Toolbar
* Paging
*/
Ext.define('Ext.ux.toolbar.Paging', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    alias: 'widget.pagebar',

    lastElements: 0,
    autoPagesize: true,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);
        if (me.autoPagesize) {
            me.on('afterlayout', function (tb, layout, eOpts) {
                var grid = tb.up('grid');
                if (!grid)
                    grid = tb.up('grid');
                grid.on('resize', function (p, aw, ah, eo) {
                    var view = p.getView(),
                        height = view.getHeight(),
                        elements = Math.floor(height / 23);
                    if (me.lastElements == elements)
                        return;
                    me.lastElements = elements;
                    me.adjustPaging(elements);

                });
            }, me, { single: true });
        }

    },

    /**
    * @private recalcPage
    * recalculate the current page after the elements per page have changed
    * @param {Number} new elements per page count
    */
    recalcPage: function (ne) {
        var me = this,
            se = ((me.store.currentPage - 1) * me.store.pageSize) + 1,
            c = me.store.currentPage,
            e = me.store.pageSize;
        return Math.floor(se / ne) + 1;
    },

    /**
    * @private adjustPaging
    * recalculate the current page after the elements per page have changed
    * @param {Number} new elements per page count
    */
    adjustPaging: function (newElements) {
        var me = this,
            newPage = me.recalcPage(newElements);
        me.store.pageSize = newElements;
        me.store.loadPage(newPage);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think you can use **anchor** layout in your window which has this grid with paging toolbar.Here is what **anchor layout** and **anchor** do :  **[Anchor Layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Anchor-cfg-anchor)**